# Running Google Dataflow with PubsubIO source for testing

Tags: java

I'm creating data-processing application using Google Cloud `Dataflow` - it is going to stream data from `Pubsub` to `Bigquery`.

I'm somewhat bewildered with infrastructure. I created my application prototype and can run it locally, using files (with `TextIO`) for source and destination.

However if I change source to `PubsubIO.Read.subscription(...)` I fail with "java.lang.IllegalStateException: no evaluator registered for PubsubIO.Read" (I am not much surprised since I see no methods to pass authentication anyway).

But how am I supposed to run this? Should I create some virtual machine in `Google Cloud Engine` and deploy stuff there, or I am supposed to describe a `job` somehow and submit it to `Dataflow API` (without caring of any explicit VM-s?)

Could you please point me to some kind of step-by-step instruction on this topic - or rather explain the workflow shortly. I'm sorry for the question is probably silly.

Answer (score 2):

You would need to run your pipeline on the Google Cloud infrastructure in order to access PubSub, see:
https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/pipelines/specifying-exec-params#CloudExecution

From their page:

```
// Create and set your PipelineOptions.
DataflowPipelineOptions options = PipelineOptionsFactory.as(DataflowPipelineOptions.class);

// For Cloud execution, set the Cloud Platform project, staging location,
// and specify DataflowPipelineRunner or BlockingDataflowPipelineRunner.
options.setProject("my-project-id");
options.setStagingLocation("gs://my-bucket/binaries");
options.setRunner(DataflowPipelineRunner.class);

// Create the Pipeline with the specified options.
Pipeline p = Pipeline.create(options);

// Specify all the pipeline reads, transforms, and writes.
...

// Run the pipeline.
p.run();
```